# Leitura sequencial de dados de um arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo, scanf

Tenho que realizar a leitura de um arquivo no qual a primeira linha representa a quantidade de alunos cadastrados e nas linhas seguintes ocorre o nome do aluno seguido da sua nota na duas provas. Parece-me que o problema esta na leitura do arquivo, mas já tentei de várias formas sanar o problema mas ele persiste.
Exemplo de arquivo:

```
3
ZE CARLOS
8.5
10.0
ANTONIO SANTOS
7.5
8.5
SEBASTIAO OLIVEIRA
5.0
6.0
```

```
int main()
{
    FILE *pFile;

    char nomearq[25];
    float *medias, temp1=0, temp2=0;
    int qntalunos, i, j;

    printf("Entre com o nome do arquivo no qual as informacoes estao armazenadas: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nomearq);

    //Abertura do arquivo em modo de leitura
    pFile=fopen(nomearq, "r");

    //Verificacao
    if(pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nErro em abrir o arquivo\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nArquivo aberto com sucesso\n\n");
    }

    //Adquirindo a quantidade de alunos presente no arquivo
    fscanf(pFile,"%d", &qntalunos);

    char nomes[qntalunos][50];

    //Alocando dinamicante
    medias=(float *)malloc(qntalunos*sizeof(float));

    //Verificando
    if(medias==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nErro na alocacao dinamica do vetor de medias\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Lendo o arquivo
    for(i=0; i<qntalunos; i++)
    {
        fgets(nomes[i],50, pFile);
        fscanf(pFile,"%f", &temp1);
        fscanf(pFile,"%f", &temp2);
        medias[i]=(temp1+temp2)/2.0;
    }

    printf("Alunos abaixo da media:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<qntalunos; i++)
    {
        if(medias[i]<7.0)
        {
            printf("Nome: %s\n", nomes[i]);
            printf("Media: %.2f\n", medias[i]);
        }
    }

    fclose(pFile);
    free(medias);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual é concretamente o erro do programa? na execução o que é que o programa faz de errado?

Comment: Nenhum dos dados esta sendo armazenado corretamente, já tentei printar eles depois, por exemplo o array de medias, e não tem nada ou aparece uns números bem loucos. O mesmo com o array de nomes

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que seu arquivo de entrada `alunos.txt` seja algo como:

```
5
ZE CARLOS
8.5
10.0
ANTONIO SANTOS
7.5
8.5
SEBASTIAO OLIVEIRA
5.0
6.0
ISAAC NEWTOW
4.0
2.5
ALBERT EINSTEIN
10.0
10.0
```

Podemos abstrair o registro de um `Aluno` usando uma `struct` para facilitar a manipulação e a legibilidade do código, vejamos:

```
struct aluno_s
{
    char  nome[50];
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
};

typedef struct aluno_s aluno_t;
```

Agora, podemos implementar a função capaz de ler os dados de um determinado arquivo e armazená-los completamente na memória:

```
int alunos_carregar( const char * arquivo, aluno_t ** alunos )
{
    FILE * arq = NULL;
    int qtd_alunos = 0;
    char linha[ LINHA_MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    aluno_t * p = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    /* abre o arquivo de alunos */
    arq = fopen( arquivo, "r");

    if( !arq )
        return -1;

    /* le a primeira linha do arquivo */
    if(!fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, arq ))
        goto erro_fatal;

    /* converte a linha lida para um inteiro representando a
     * quantidade alunos no arquivo*/
    qtd_alunos = atoi(linha);

    /* aloca memoria necessaria para acomodar os alunos
     * que serao lidos */
    p = (aluno_t*) malloc( qtd_alunos * sizeof(aluno_t) );

    if(!p)
        goto erro_fatal;

    /* Para cada aluno no arquivo... */
    for( i = 0; i < qtd_alunos; i++ )
    {
        /* le a linha contendo o nome do aluno */
        if(!fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, arq ))
            goto erro_fatal;

        /* remove os finalizadores de linha contidos no buffer */
        linha[strcspn(linha, "\r\n")] = 0;

        /* copia o nome do aluno para a memoria */
        strncpy( p[i].nome, linha, NOME_ALUNO_MAX_TAM );

        /* le a linha que representa a primeira nota do aluno */
        if(!fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, arq ))
            goto erro_fatal;

        /* converte a linha lida para um float */
        p[i].nota1 = atof(linha);

        /* le a linha que representa a segunda nota do aluno */
        if(!fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, arq ))
            goto erro_fatal;

        /* converte a linha lida para um float */
        p[i].nota2 = atof(linha);
    }

    /* fecha o arquivo de alunos */
    fclose(arq);

    /* retorna lista de alunos usando o ponteiro para
     * ponteiro passado com argumento */
    *alunos = p;

    /* retorna a quantidade de alunos na lista */
    return qtd_alunos;

erro_fatal:

    if(arq)
        fclose(arq);

    if(p)
        free(p);

    *alunos = NULL;

    return -1; /* erro fatal */
}
```

Uma vez que temos os dados bem estruturados na memória, podemos pensar na função capaz de exibí-los na tela:

```
void alunos_exibir( aluno_t * alunos, int qtd_alunos, float media_min )
{
    int i = 0;
    float media = 0.0;

    /* para cada aluno... */
    for( i = 0; i < qtd_alunos; i++ )
    {
        /* calcula a media do aluno */
        media = (alunos[i].nota1 + alunos[i].nota2) / 2.0;

        /* se a media for menor que a media minima, exibe aluno */
        if( media < media_min )
        {
            printf( "Nome: %s\n", alunos[i].nome );
            printf( "  Nota1: %0.2f\n", alunos[i].nota1 );
            printf( "  Nota2: %0.2f\n", alunos[i].nota2 );
            printf( "  Media: %0.2f\n", media );
            printf( "\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

E finalmente, nossa `main()` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
int main( void )
{
    aluno_t * alunos = NULL;
    int qtd = 0;

    qtd = alunos_carregar( "alunos.txt", &alunos );

    if( qtd < 0 )
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo de entrada.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    alunos_exibir( alunos, qtd,  7.0 );

    free( alunos );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Saída:

```
Nome: SEBASTIAO OLIVEIRA
  Nota1: 5.00
  Nota2: 6.00
  Media: 5.50

Nome: ISAAC NEWTOW
  Nota1: 4.00
  Nota2: 2.50
  Media: 3.25
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/VibrantEsteemedTriangles)